# Manage/Restrict access of users, contacts and leads in AppExchange product DocuSign

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am using AppExchange product DocuSign for sending documents to end-user for digital signature in one of the objects in SFDC.

I am doing it using 'Send with DocuSign' button in the detail page. My questions are:

1. Can we manage/restrict the addition of recipients based on relationship? for example:  I have contacts available to opportunity. In the opportunity detail page i want that sender can only select contacts from the list of contacts associated with the opportunity.  Or add as recipients only users of particular profiles/roles etc.
2. Can we also control the visibility of buttons highlighted in the below screen shot?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the answer to both is no, as long as you are using the managed package.  There are lots of ways (using custom buttons, for example) to skip the screen you see above, and "program" button to send just the people you want to send, however.